# How to change a array to a arraylist effectively

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have array variable declared like this:

```
public class carshop {
    int numofcars = 0;
    int maxcars = 10;
    ACar[] allCars;
    private CarShop;

public CarShop() { //Car Constructor
    maxcars = maxE;
    allCars = new ACar[maxcars];
    }
}
```

In my coding example, every time a user adds a new car (via string input), it will increase the numofcars by 1. I have tried changing the array type into a arraylist

```
ArrayList<ACar> allCars = new ArrayList<ACar>(Arrays.asList());
```

I changed the `allCars = new ACar[maxcars];` line into this: `allCars =  ACar.add(maxcars);`

However now eclipse is giving me errors saying "The method add(int) is undefined for the type ACar".

Can you tell me what I have done wrong? Sorry if I have explained this poorly.

Comment: What is `ACar`? How is it defined?

Comment: Where are you using `add`?

Comment: First problem: you've declared a type called `carshop` but your constructor is for `CarShop`. Now why are you trying to call `add` at all in your initialization? And why are you reinitializing the variable when you've already got an initializer? That initializer could be simpler as: `List<ACar> allCars = new ArrayList<>();` as well...

Comment: Java is case-sensitive -- the constructor and class declaration must be named the same...

Comment: If you want to change the Array in your code to an ArrayList consider that they have some differences: An ArrayList doesn't have a fixed size, it grows as you add Objects to it. So if your logic requires your list to have a maximum length (as your variable maxcars suggests) you should probably choose something different than a Standard ArrayList or be aware that you have to handle yourself that a maximum of 10 cars can get added.

Comment: Programming means more than just concatenating arbitrary words. What is `allCars =  ACar.add(maxcars);` supposed to mean? Did you ever take a second to think about what you have written? Even the parts not related to your question are a bunch of words, forming invalid code. As already mentioned in previous comments, your spelling of `carshop` and `CarShop` is inconsistent, but besides that, there is a spurious declaration `private CarShop;` in the middle of the code where it’s even impossible to guess what it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ACar is an array so it doesn't have the add() method and you need to insert values by doing `ACar[x] = value;`

If you want to easily convert an array to a List you can just do:

```
List<ACar> carList = Arrays.asList(allCars);
```

or for ArrayList specifically:

```
ArrayList<ACar> carList = new ArrayList<ACar>(Arrays.asList(allCars));
```

However you should also think about why you have both an array and an ArrayList. You could instead just be doing:

```
List<ACar> carList = new ArrayList<ACar>(maxCars);
```

The maxCars variable is optional, you don't need to set the initial size of an ArrayList unless you are trying to optimise the code.

Comment: That doesn't convert to an ArrayList. It converts to a List (which is also named ArrayList but is not a java.util.ArrayList), which is not resizable as an ArrayList is, and is backed by the original array.